# Problema al ejecutar subprocess.Popen en Mac

Tags: python-2.7, macos, latex

Actualmente uso el siguiente código para compilar archivos de LaTeX con Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import os
from pdb import set_trace as bp
import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/MiKTeX Console.app/Contents/bin/')

def compila_latex(nombre):

    # Antes de compilar vamos a borar os posibles archivos auxiliares preexistentes que pueden dar error en la compilación

    delete_files(nombre, ['.pdf', '.tex'])
    cmd  = ['pdflatex','-interaction','nonstopmode', nombre + '.tex']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.communicate()

    retcode = proc.returncode
    if not retcode == 0:
        os.unlink(nombre + '.pdf')
        raise ValueError('Hay un error con la compilación del documento.')

    print('Realizada 1ª compilación del documento.')

    cmd  = ['pdflatex','-interaction','nonstopmode', nombre + '.tex']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.communicate()

    retcode = proc.returncode
    if not retcode == 0:
        os.unlink(nombre + '.pdf')
        raise ValueError('Error')

    print('Realizada 2ª compilación del documento.')

    delete_files(nombre, ['.pdf', '.tex'])

    print('Eliminados documentos auxiliares.')
```

delete_files es otra función de la misma librería que elimina todos los documentos auxiliares que se generan al compilar un archivo .tex, y `nombres el nombre del archivo que se ha creado con otro código distinto.

Toda esto funciona perfectamente en Ubuntu 16.04, pero me arroja el siguiente error al ejecutarlo todo exactamente de la misma forma en macOs High Sierra 10.13.6 en la primera vez que aparece `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout...`:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

El archivo sí que está creado en el mismo directorio donde está el script original que lo genera y, como ya digo, toda la estructura de directorios y la forma de ejecutarlo era idéntica en Ubuntu, por lo que pienso que el problema puede venir por la forma en que Mac trata las rutas de los archivos o algo así, pero soy nuevo con este SO y no tengo ni idea.

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Use el parámetro `shell=True` para `Popen`.

Comment: Al usarlo no se produce el error de antes, pero entra en el if y falla diciendo que no existe el archivo nombre + .pdf para poder borrarlo, es decir, que no está llegando a compilarlo

Comment: ¿`pdflatex` lo tienes accesible desde el PATH? ¿podrías intentar ejecutar el comando exacto por la terminal y ver que error te arroja?

Comment: Al final he conseguido solucionarlo: pdflatex se había instalado en una carpeta que no es la típica /bin o /usr, y por eso he tenido que añadir la ruta completa junto al primer argumento de cmd. Muchas gracias por la ayuda igualmente!